# Get PHP file in Bootbox message field

Tags: php, jquery, bootbox

For those who are familiar bootbox you may be able to do this.

What I'm trying to do is get an php file inside of a modal box. Below is the code:

```
$('#testBootBox').click(function(e){
    bootbox.dialog({
        title: "Test",
        message: pageInsertion();
    });
});

function pageInsertion(){
    var form = "<?php include('TestPage.php'); ?>";
    return form;
}
```

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: You can do that with ajax...you call the ajax function that called the server side script `TestPage.php` and then render the output on the client side indise your bootbox dialog

Comment: could you explain with some code or where online I can get a similar example?

Comment: I can give you a complete answer, but first, if you run your `TestPage.php` it runs good, without any error?

Comment: Yes it does. It contains mostly filler html5 code and some php

Comment: Did it work? If you have any problem just let me know, ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish that task easily using `Ajax` in order to render your *server response* on the *client*:

```
$(function(){
    $('#testBootBox').click(function(e){
      $.ajax({
          url:'testpage.php',
          type:'get'
      }).done(function(response){
        bootbox.dialog({
          title: "Test",
          message: response;
        });
      });
    });
}):
```

Answer (score 0):

Just render this form in hidden div. Like so:

```
<div id="hiddendiv" style="display: none;"><?php include('TestPage.php'); ?></div>
<script>
     $('#testBootBox').click(function(e){
         bootbox.dialog({
             title: "Test",
             message: $('#hiddendiv').html()
         });
     });
</script>
```

Or you can put html directly:

```
<script>
     <?php
         ob_start();
         ob_implicit_flush(false);
         require include('TestPage.php');
         $form = json_encode(ob_get_clean());
     ?>
     $('#testBootBox').click(function(e){
         bootbox.dialog({
             title: "Test",
             message: <?php echo $form; ?>
         });
     });
</script>
```

Or use ajax like in previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hackerman thanks for the help . You only had one error...a semicolon wasn't suppose to be after the response. lol . Below is the full answer.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){



$('#testBootBox').click(function(e){
        $.ajax({
            url:'TestPage.php',
            type:'get'
        }).done(function(response){
          bootbox.dialog({
            title: "Test",
            message: response
          });
        });
  }); 






  });
```